# how do invoke this custom jquery function

Tags: javascript

Here is the link to the function :

https://github.com/darcyclarke/jQuery-Flickr-Photo-Plugin/blob/master/jquery.flickrPhoto-1.0.js

Not sure if I should put it inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

And then how do I call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Notice:

If you'd look closer, you'd see http://jsfiddle.net/darcyclarke/Fg9Ah/14/light or http://jsfiddle.net/Fg9Ah/53

Or even more http://darcyclarke.me/development/get-flickr-photos-from-urls-with-jquery/

## Answer:

All jQuery calls is better to put inside `$(function(){ /* your code here */ });` same as document ready. And regarding function call, then just

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    var settings = {};
    $('#place_it_in_here').flickrPhoto( settings );
});
</script>
<div id="place_it_in_here"></div>
```

Comment: Answers should be self contained, so please include the actual solution in your post. Right now this is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will need to be inside `$(document).ready()` or something similar to ensure the DOM element is extent. As per the docs, you'll need to know the url, key, and secret:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.photo').flickrVideo({ 
        url : 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/rj3/5641046720/', 
        key : 'yourKey', 
        secret : 'yourSecret'
    });
});
```